# ASP.NET MVC Web API Paste XML as Types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The old [WCF Rest Starter Kit](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/24644) had a interesting feature. It was an additonal Visual Studio menu option under `Edit` called `Paste XML as Types`. You can see this in action here on [Tim Heuer's blog post concerning the tool](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/04/29/paste-your-rest-api-as-strong-type-in-visual-studio.aspx).

The WCF REST Starter kit is depreciated in favour of [ASP.NET MVC Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api), but does the feature, or a similar feature still exist? Or alternatively, `Paste JSON as Types`?

It would be useful to have a tool in Visual Studio where you can paste a JSON or XML example and get a class generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a blog post about exactly this problem/feature here:

http://www.jphellemons.nl/post/Use-JSON-resource-in-AspNet-C-super-easy-and-fast.aspx

Mads Kristensen's web essentials package does what you need (among other things):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6

Comment: Oh no! There are a couple of apps out there that do it, if you have a look on codeplex I've seen some. Would be nice to have them built in tho, I agree!